# Playing a sound effect in windows phone 7.1 by tapping a canvas

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am making a simple app using windows phone sdk 7.1, I need to play a short sound effect whenever the user taps a canvas. How can I add this future in the `Tap` event of the canvas or any other control?

All I know is the `Uri` to the file in the project folder:

```
"/TestApp;component/Resources/Untitled.wma"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I figured out the correct way to be:

```
private void PlayDuuuu()
{
    StreamResourceInfo stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/AppName;component/Untitled.wav", UriKind.Relative));
    SoundEffect soundeffect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream.Stream);
    SoundEffectInstance soundInstance = soundeffect.CreateInstance();
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    soundInstance.Play();
}
```

Also I found out that the sound file can not be in WMA format...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the `SoundEffectPlayer` from [PhoneyTools](http://phoney.codeplex.com/). Declare it like this in your class

```
SoundEffectPlayer _player = null;
```

Initialize it with

```
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/TestApp;component/Resources/Untitled.wma", UriKind.Relative));
var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(resource.Stream);
_player = new SoundEffectPlayer(effect);
```

and then simply call

```
_player.Play();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what using statement I should declare for `SoundEffect` ?

Answer (score 1):

I find the following solution to be best in order to play sound notifications. It also plays .WMA files.

```
public static void PlayMessageFailedSound()
    {
        var s = Song.FromUri("MessageFailed", new Uri(@"Resources/Alert_nudge.wma", UriKind.Relative));
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        MediaPlayer.Play(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a media element control, set it's source property to you file and simply call the player.Play() in tap event handler